# Comparing two Arrays and return the duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

I have two arrays and I would like to compare them and return all the values that are on both, even if they repeat.

```js
const correctValue = ['0', '1'];
const actualValue = [
    ['0', '2', '0', 'E', '1', '1', 'u', '0', '1', '0', ':', '1'],
    ['0', '0', '1', 'u', '0', '}', '1', 'l', '1', '1', '1', '˜'],
    ['x', 'k', 'e', '2', '|', '[', 'z', '8', 's', 'd', '2', '5'],
    ['r', '8', '6', ']', '2', '6', 'H', ';', 'Á', 'l', 'm', '?'],
    ['Y', '0', '0', '1', '1', '7', '1', '.', '0', 'v', '0', '1']
];
```

Comment: Please provide what have you done till now?. Also provide sample input and expected output

Comment: Do you mean intersection? Then your question might already be answered under https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37041756/4267015 duplicate

Comment: I only have those two arrays. I would like to create a new array with all the "0" and "1" from the "actualValue" array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this  Solution:-

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>




<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
const correctValue = ['0', '1'];
const actualValue = [
    ['0', '2', '0', 'E', '1', '1', 'u', '0', '1', '0', ':', '1'],
    ['0', '0', '1', 'u', '0', '}', '1', 'l', '1', '1', '1', '˜'],
    ['x', 'k', 'e', '2', '|', '[', 'z', '8', 's', 'd', '2', '5'],
    ['r', '8', '6', ']', '2', '6', 'H', ';', 'Á', 'l', 'm', '?'],
    ['Y', '0', '0', '1', '1', '7', '1', '.', '0', 'v', '0', '1']
];

function myFunction() {
var same_values=[];
for(var i=0;i<correctValue.length;i++)
{
    for(var j=0;j<actualValue.length;j++)
   {    
        for(var k =0;k<actualValue[j].length;k++)
           {
             if(correctValue[i]==actualValue[j][k])
              {
                same_values.push(actualValue[j][k])
              }
            }
    }
}
console.log(same_values)
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it, but its not logging anything

Comment: i have updated the code with HTML template. please try this in a html document or in any editor.

Answer (score 0):

```
function compareArrays(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr1.reduce((acc, item) {
    if (arr2.includes(item)) {
      acc.push(item)
    }
    return acc
  },[])
}
```

Not most efficient solution, but it works
Need to specify if you need only unique values or not
The best will be if you write expected output

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it but it's giving me a syntax error on the first line, the function line.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to name the function, you can try once more

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Try this:

```
arr1.filter(e => arr2.includes(e));
```

Working demo:

```js
 

function duplicate(arr1, arr2) {
   return arr1.filter(e => arr2.includes(e));
}

var duplicates = [];

const correctValue = ['0', '1'];
const actualValue = [
['0', '2', '0', 'E', '1', '1', 'u', '0', '1', '0', ':', '1'],
['0', '0', '1', 'u', '0', '}', '1', 'l', '1', '1', '1', '˜'],
['x', 'k', 'e', '2', '|', '[', 'z', '8', 's', 'd', '2', '5'],
['r', '8', '6', ']', '2', '6', 'H', ';', 'Á', 'l', 'm', '?'],
['Y', '0', '0', '1', '1', '7', '1', '.', '0', 'v', '0', '1']
];

actualValue.forEach(arr => duplicates.push(duplicate(correctValue, arr)))

console.log(duplicates);
```

Comment: It's not returning all the values. The output: [ [ '0', '1' ], [ '0', '1' ], [], [], [ '0', '1' ] ]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to achieve what you are doing. 
In this approach, I am filtering each row in actualValue and concatenating the outputs.

```
const correctValue = ['0', '1'];
const actualValue = [
['0', '2', '0', 'E', '1', '1', 'u', '0', '1', '0', ':', '1'],
['0', '0', '1', 'u', '0', '}', '1', 'l', '1', '1', '1', '˜'],
['x', 'k', 'e', '2', '|', '[', 'z', '8', 's', 'd', '2', '5'],
['r', '8', '6', ']', '2', '6', 'H', ';', 'Á', 'l', 'm', '?'],
['Y', '0', '0', '1', '1', '7', '1', '.', '0', 'v', '0', '1']];

actualValue.reduce((arr, listData)=> arr.concat(listData.filter(data => correctValue.includes(data))),[])
console.log(output) //["0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1"]
```